# grails controller/action/id automagically turning into controller/index

Tags: grails-2.0

My problem is that the backend server (written in grails) is automatically converting my request URL to be a different URL.  Specifically, it is changing it from /UXChallengeAwards/processSelectedNotifications to /UXChallengeAwards/index.

--

In a template gsp file, I have defined a button that makes a jQuery ajax call when clicked on:

```
<button class="blue-link"
    onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', 
    data:jQuery(this).parents('.multiSelectForm').serialize(), 
    url: '/ici/UXChallengeAwards/processSelectedNotifications/${challenge.id}',
    success:function(data,textStatus){},
    error:function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown){}
    })"  >
```

The method UXChallengeAwardsController.processSelectedNotifications exists.  It performs some work and then redirects to another action in the controller.  In fact, this used to work.  But somehow in the process of adding a second button I made a change which seems to have broken things.

When the button is now clicked,  the request URL gets switched to /ici/UXChallengeAwards/index and a 404 is returned because index does not exist as an action in this controller.

I've googled, and the most common answer for when this happens is that a controller must return some results for the view.  But I've seen plenty of examples of redirects in controllers, and I do not see what I am doing wrong.  (I did try variants of rendering results, but with no success.)

Here is what my controller action looks like:

```
  def  processSelectedNotifications = {
      def challenge
      def checkboxes = params.list('selectCheckbox');
      for (checkbox in checkboxes) {  
      // the checkbox contains the id of a ChallangeAward that should be published
         ChallengeAwards challengeAwards = ChallengeAwards.get(checkbox.toInteger())
         if (challengeAwards) {
            // grab a challenge for use in the redirect, they are all the same
            challenge=challengeAwards.challenge
            publish(challengeAwards)
          }
      }       
      if (challenge) {
        redirect  action: 'challengeAwardsRemote', id: challenge.id
        return      
      }

      // render a failure message if we got here
      render messageNS(code:"UX.ChallengeAwards.Publish.failure")
    }
```

I would really appreciate any insights into what might be wrong, or how to go about tackling this issue. I've checked my UrlMappings, and this is the rule that should handle this controller/method request:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{  constraints {} }
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question, in case it is helpful for other newbies.

It turns out that I was not getting an automatic redirect.  Rather,  I had an error in the button setup code,  so that grails was using its default link behavior. (Which is to go to the controller that matches the view, and if no action is specified, use the index method.)

The code above was originally created using a remoteSubmit tag, but I found that the generated code did not support handling multiple forms on a single page very well.  So, I copied that generated code and then tweaked it to handle the multiple forms.  However, I wanted the styling to match up with what was already in place on the page, so I switched it to be a button.  That's when things went awry.

Eventually,  I ended up specifying an onClick function for the button, and then writing the ajax submit code in javascript.  Which turned out to be much simpler.

Here is what the button specification ended up looking like:

```
<button type="submit" id="notifications" class="blue-link"   >
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
<g:messageNS
code="UX.DiscussionBoard.ChallengeAward.Button.notify" />   
</button>
```

And the associated JavaScript:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var clkBtn = "";
    jQuery('button[type="submit"]').click(function(evt) {
    clkBtn = evt.target.id;
    });

    jQuery('.multiSelectForm').submit(function()  {

    var url = '/ici/UXChallengeAwards/processSelectedNotifications';
    if (clkBtn == 'deletes') {
    url ='/ici/UXChallengeAwards/processSelectedDeletes';
    } 

    var errorTarget = jQuery(this).parents().find('.recipientMessage').val();
    var requestData = jQuery(this).parents('.multiSelectForm').serialize();
    var options = {
    data : requestData,
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    target : '#awardsTab',
    error : function(data) {
    jQuery('#' + errorTarget).html(data.responseText).show();
    },
    success : function(data) {
    console.log("in success");
    }
    };

jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
return false;
});
```